# Can't find Visual C++ Templates 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm a programmer working on learning C++ for personal projects. I recently downloaded Visual Studio 2013. The problem is this: when I go to create a new project, I can't find the templates for C++ Win 32 Console Application. According to the walkthrough on Microsoft's website (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235629.aspx), I should be able to just open a C++ project. This isn't working because the option simply isn't there. I thought I might need to install the template but can't find any online. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio did you download? What **do** you see available in the Templates? Is there no section called "Visual C++"?

Comment: Did you install Visual Studio 2013 Desktop Express?

Answer (score 0):

I just performed a fresh install of Visual Studio 2013 directly from MSDN. Here's what I see what I click on File -> New -> Project:

[image]

So I can tell you that it ***should*** be there.

What version of Visual Studio did you download? If you downloaded [the Express Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) (Free version [available at their website](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)), make sure that you download "[Express 2013 for Windows Desktop](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop)". The other versions are specialized versions that won't include the standard Visual Basic, C#, or C++ support.

If you downloaded Express 2013 for Windows Desktop or you purchased Visual Studio 2013 and still do not see it, then I would suggest performing a re-install. There really isn't a reason otherwise that this portion of the install would be missing.